# What does org.freedesktop.systemd1 mean?

Tags: 14.04, reboot

Running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

I had an unexpected server reboot and I found the following messages in the syslog:

```
Jan  3 09:57:09 zipsrv kernel: [21010082.798946] usb 1-1.1: new low-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
Jan  3 09:57:09 zipsrv kernel: [21010082.905790] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2105
Jan  3 09:57:09 zipsrv kernel: [21010082.905795] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jan  3 09:57:09 zipsrv kernel: [21010082.905799] usb 1-1.1: Product: Dell USB Keyboard
Jan  3 09:57:09 zipsrv kernel: [21010082.905802] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Dell
Jan  3 09:57:09 zipsrv kernel: [21010082.922485] input: Dell Dell USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/input/input10
Jan  3 09:57:09 zipsrv kernel: [21010082.922725] hid-generic 0003:413C:2105.0009: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Dell USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:16.0-1.1/input0
Jan  3 09:57:11 zipsrv kernel: [21010085.160537] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 11
Jan  3 09:57:27 zipsrv dbus[415]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' (using servicehelper)
Jan  3 09:57:27 zipsrv dbus[415]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'
Jan  3 09:57:28 zipsrv kernel: [21010101.664575] init: tty4 main process (1064) killed by TERM signal
```

The USB keyboard connection message is strange and it occurs frequently. It started 3 minutes before the reboot and repeated every 30 seconds.

It might be something with KVM over IP system broken in the datacenter. I'm trying to clarify that with support team. Even after reboot it continues to appear every 4 minutes 30 seconds.

I just want to clarify what might have happened?

I have checked

```
  grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | less
```

I have not found anything. Also there was not any successful login.

What does `Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1'` mean?

Comment: We had this exact thing happen to us this morning. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: I was just having the same issue so I had a quick Google to find the answer. This question popped up, obviously unanswered, and then I saw https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/. It seems that it is part of the service manager, or something like that!